# Lotus Connections - autologin for 3rd party app

Tags: authentication, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm creating an iWidget for Lotus Connections that provides access to our 3rd party application.

When the user loads the widget, we would sign him into our system automatically and gain access to the Connections REST API using his account to add activities.

What's the recommended way to handle authentication with 3rd parties, ideally without having the user set up anything manually in the iWidget?

Thank you for any advice you can share.

Answer (score 1):

well you can have stored credentials to access you backend service, from the iwidget you can get the identity of the user, and act on behalf of the user.

iContext -> getUserProfile()
then you can get the identity.

that's probably the quickest way to get started.  there are more complex solutions which mediate the ltpa token and whatever single sign on provider you have in your environment.

I'm also not sure that iWidgets can act as oauth consumers, maybe someone else knows more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll use the profile data to get started and research the SSO solutions.

Comment: I would be interested in hearing more about this. If you have any details or anything you can share.